# Automate: Tracing an established MS SQL database. (All Tables, Col Headers)

Tags: sql-server, database, select, rows

**How can I perform a Microsoft SQL query on an entire database, so that it takes only the first 5 rows of each table?**

This would give me a nice overview of entire schema.(I hope) I tried a database diagram very slow and you can only see tables and headers. I have been doing this task manually and that is also taking forever.

Ultimately, I would want to have the data export to excel or just be able to review the results.

Example output would be:

```
Table 1 - (Showing Column Headers and Actual Data)
ROW 1 Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
ROW 2 Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
ROW 3 Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
ROW 4 Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
ROW 5 Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4

Table 2 - (Showing Column Headers and Data)
ROW 1 Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
ROW 2 Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
ROW 3 Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
ROW 4 Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
ROW 5 Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
```

My SQL Code:

```
SELECT TOP 5 *
FROM * TABLES
WHILE SELECTED < DATABASE
```

- Not sure how to say from all tables, then gather and print that and repeat like a while loop until it runs down the entire database.

all help is greatly appreciated. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cursor` and `dynamic sql` for this.

```
DECLARE table_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT name
FROM sys.tables
WHERE type = 'U';

DECLARE @table varchar(100);

OPEN table_cursor;

FETCH NEXT FROM table_cursor
INTO @table;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    EXEC('select TOP 5 * from ' + @table);
    FETCH NEXT FROM table_cursor
    INTO @table;
END;

CLOSE table_cursor;
DEALLOCATE table_cursor;
```